# ActiveRecord Delete...?

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-1.9.3

I'm just starting to learn ActiveRecord, and I am just trying out little things to figure out how everything works. I just tried the following code on the following sqlite3 database.

Ruby:

```
class Balances < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize
    @balance = 50
    update_attribute(:balance, @balance)
  end
  def withdraw amount
    update_attribute(:balance, @balance-amount)
  end
end
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE balance(
    balance 50
);
```

When I write:

```
balance = Balances.new
```

I Get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:28:in `write_attribute'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:67:in `write_attribute'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:14:in `balance='
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:180:in `update_attribute'
```

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I notice several things:

- The class name should be `Balance` (capitalized, singular). The table name in the database will be lower case, plural. Eg, `balances`
- Don't define an `initialize` method for an ActiveRecord model. Instead use `after_initialize` callback. [A post](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html). Also, the [Rails docs.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

**Added** Also, the file name for the model should be `balance.rb` (lower case, singular)

**Added some more** You probably don't want to change the balance of the record back to 50 every time an instance of the record is initialized. -- That's what your example is currently doing. If you want to set the opening balance of new records in the database to be 50, then use the "before_create" callback.

Remember that ActiveRecord model classes are associated with, but different from, the records in the underlying database. For example, you can create an instance of an ActiveRecord model, and then **not** create a matching record in the database. -- The database record will only be created when and if you call the save or create methods.